# Upgrading from log4j-core 2.8.2 to version 2.13.2 stopped writing to logs

Tags: java, log4j2

I work on an application with Java 8 and upgraded log4j-core 2.8.2 to 2.13.2 to solve the blackjack vulnerability problem in log4j-core 2.8.2. I also upgraded log4j-api version to 2.13.2 (in pom.xml, using maven). The vulnerability is resolved. But the application activity is not being logged into the logs. The autosys job activity like batch loading, feed processing, etc is being written successfully to the logs. Anything that is done on the application side (login, logout, processing, downloading reports, etc) doesn't write to logs.

I also tried upgrading to slf4j higher but that didn't help either. Can someone please suggest or give clues ?

This is how the logger object is created in the application:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyServlet.class);
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm upgrading from 2.12.1 to 2.13.x but it also stopped logging once upgraded to 2.13.x